# "we all have experienced" or "we have all experienced"?

Tags: word-order

Tell me please which sentence is correct.

> We **all** have experienced hardship.
>
> We have **all** experienced hardship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. The only difference is a subtle shift in emphasis (too subtle to worry about, really). *We have all experienced* is the more "relaxed" form, but grouping *we all* together might be useful in emphasizing a specific group (akin to "all twelve of us have experienced hardship" as opposed to "all people have experienced hardship"). This isn't a rule, only a thought; consider them interchangeable.